# How to enter data into the instagram entry fields via JS?

Tags: javascript, web, input, user-input

Tried different ways.

> document.getElementsByName('username')[0].focus();
>
> document.getElementsByName('username')[0].value = "123";

Displays the data on top of the field, but it is not taken into account when sending.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL0o2.png)

Comment: You need to remove the placeholder when you enter a value. `document.getElementsByName('username')[0].placeholder = "";`

Comment: Let me know if this solves your issue

Comment: @ABDULLOKH MUKHAMMADJONOV , Unfortunately, that didn't help.